# Mutual inductance circuit analysis

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

given the following circuit, I need to find $ I_1(t) $ and $ I_2(t) $ 
(forgive my microsoft paint skills ;) )

[image]

I've come up with a solution, and I wish to check with you if it is current or, better yet, if there are easier ways to solve this problem:

step 1: derive the differential equations:

1. $$\epsilon=I_1R+LdI_1/dt+MdI_2/dt $$
2. $$I_2R+LdI_2/dt+MdI_1/dt=0 $$
   step 2: I now use $I'$ and $I''$ as followed
   $$ I' = I_1+I_2 $$
   $$ I''=I_1-I_2 $$
   this leads me to solve the following equations:
   $$dI'/dt+R/(L+M) I'=\epsilon/(L+M) $$
   $$dI''/dt+R/(L-M) I'=\epsilon/(L-M) $$
   ill spare the solving part (solving a Non-homogonous linear eq' and an homogonous linear eq).

step 3: the solution is:
$$I_1+I_2=I'=\epsilon/R (1-exp(-Rt/(L+M)))$$
$$I_1-I_2=I''=\epsilon/R (1-exp(-Rt/(L-M)))$$

therefore the final solution for $I_1$ and $I_2$ I received is
$$I_1=\epsilon/2R \cdot (2-exp(-Rt/(L+M)-exp(-Rt/(L-M))$$
$$I_2=\epsilon/2R \cdot (exp(-Rt/(L+M)-exp(-Rt/(L-M))$$

would appreciate your response!

Comment: Your diagram shows mutual inductance, not conductance. Can you correct it to make your intention clear? Also, you should include a dot on each inductor to show the sign of the coupling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution looks good to me, you are unlikely to find a formal solution much shorter than yours. It may or may not make the solution slightly easier to use the equivalent circuit for two mutual inductors, involving an ideal transformer.

[image: Mutual inductors equivalent circuit]

In general, you use
$$ L_{l1} = \left(1 - \frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}} \right)L_1 $$
$$ L_{l2} = \left(1 - \frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}} \right)L_2 $$
$$ L_{Mag} = \frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}}L_1 $$
$$ N_1 : N_2 = L_1^2:L_2^2. $$

The transformer is nice because it lets you refer any impedance on the secondary to the primary. In some cases, especially when $ M = \sqrt{L_1 L_2} $, this equivalent circuit is often more convenient to work with.